# authwithcustomtoken not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase

In my project I am writing e2e tests in node.js and I have a test firebase I am using. So I create a token in node before each describe in the test runs and then I send it to the front end(angular.js) and then I use the authWithCustomToken function to authenticate the person.

The problem is for some reason it isn't even calling the function because I put a console.log statement in the callback and every time my code runs it enters the if $location.search condition but the console.log doesn't print out anything. I dont seem to know what the problem is.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require('firebase-token-generator');
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://xxxxx');
var data = require('./data_helper.js');

rootRef.child('users').set(data.users[0]);

var credentials =  {
  nonAdmin: {
    uid: 'google', 
    email: 'xxxx'
  },
  admin: {
    uid: 'google', 
    email: 'xxxxx'
  }
};


var logInAndThen = function(options) {
  var secret = 'sdmdfmdsjwdsjwjwwewewe';
  var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(secret);
  var token = tokenGenerator.createToken(credentials[options.userType || 'admin']);

  browser.get('/login?token=' + token);

  var alertDiv = by.className('alert');
  //browser.wait(function(){});
  var waitOnFirebase = browser.wait(function() {
    return browser.isElementPresent(alertDiv);
  });

  waitOnFirebase.then(function(data) {
    console.log('-------', data);
    options.cb(data);
  });
};

module.exports = logInAndThen;
```

--------- FRONT END ANGULAR CODE PUT IN APPLICATION.RUN---------------------

```
if($location.search().token) {
    console.log(Refs.root.toString());  
    Refs.root.authWithCustomToken($location.search().token, function(err, authData) { 
      console.log(err,authData);
    }, {scope: 'email'});
  }
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this

Comment: How are you "sending it to the front end" exactly?

Comment: i am sending the token to the front end by attaching it as a query paramter in the url e.g. browser.get('/login?token=' + token);

Comment: so are you getting the $location with angular and extracting the token from it?

Comment: @tpie that's right. Anytime the page loads, it would check the url path to see if there is a token query parameter. If there is, it would use the token to authenticate the person

Comment: are you seeing it appear in the browser bar?  can you get angular to console.log that $location?

Comment: Also..just curious, but why are you doing it this way?  Why don't you have angular request the token, and send it back that way?

Comment: i can see it in the browser and i have used angular to console.log the token several times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75622/discussion-between-tpie-and-user3775998).

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the token like this (put this in your `.run`):

```
    var loc = $location.path();
    if(loc.search('login?token') > 0) {
      token = loc.splice(13)
      //now incorporate the 'token' into whatever auth functions you need to.
    }
```

Not entirely sure if this is the most technically 'correct' way of grabbing the token, but it should work for you.